# How to get started developing on *nix

Tags: linux

Is there a good 'how-to' or 'getting started' guide for getting started using g++ and gdb?

Some background.  Decent programmer, but so far I have done everything on Windows in Visual Studio.

I have a little experience using terminal to compile files (not much beyond a .h and 1 or 2 .cpp).  But nothing beyond that.

Anyone know of a good primer on on how to get started coding on Linux?

Comment: You might want to ask for clarification on the no "IDE" rule. IDEs are used on Linux just as much as in Windows. If you're allowed to use an IDE on Windows, it doesn't make sense to not be allowed to under Linux.

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask these kind of questions, but I will give you this link to point you in the right direction. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keWNLqW31r4

Comment: Another link to get started: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html

Comment: @NikosChantziaras I like your link better.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras: I suspect that the point of the restriction is to force people out of the IDE bubble so that they experience what it is that the IDE is hiding from you (and deciding for you).  This can be either traumatic or liberating, depending on your perspective.  As someone who has never programmed professionally within an IDE (unless you count `emacs`) I personally believe the latter.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras: I never use any IDE for C or C++ or MELT programming. I only use `emacs`. And most GCC contributors don't use any IDE, so you can code under Linux without IDEs.

Comment: Just do as you are told: Learn `vi`, `make`, `gcc` and `gdb` and your done for the first round. Then go for learning `sh`, `grep`, `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: And btw @other commenters: I'd consider `emacs` being at least a 'sort of' IDE.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be looking for an editor. Others have already mentioned emacs and vi. Coming from a Windows world you might like the Geany editor. If you're willing to spend a little money I've always been a fan of [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/). Welcome to the world of *nix! I made the switch in 1998 and haven't regretted it once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read some good books, notably [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/). Read also the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and other documentation from [Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/)

Obviously, install some Linux distribution on your laptop (not in some VM, but on real disk partitions). If you have a debian like distribution, run `aptitude build-dep gcc-4.6 gedit` on it to get a lot of interesting developers packages.

Learn some command line skills. Learn to use the `man` command; after installing `manpages` and `manpages-dev` packages, type `man man` (use the space bar to "scroll text", the `q` key to quit). Read also the [intro(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/intro.2.html) man page. When you forgot how to use a command like `cp` try `cp --help`.

Use a version control system like [git](http://scm-git.com/), even for one person tiny projects.

Backup your files.

Read several relevant Wikipedia pages on [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29), [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix), [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix)

Try hard to use the command line. For instance, try to do everything on the command line for a week or more. Avoid using your desktop, and possibly your mouse. Learn to use `emacs`.

Read about builder programs like [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Retrieve several free software from their source code (e.g. from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) or [freecode](http://freecode.com/) or [github](http://github.com/)) and practice building and compiling them. Study their source code

Basic tips to start (if a command is not found, you need to install the package providing it) in command line (in a terminal).

- run `emacs` ; there is a tutorial menu; practice it for half an hour.
- edit a `helloworld.c` program (with a `main` calling some `hello` function)
- compile it with `gcc -g -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld`; improve your code till no warnings are given. Always pass `-Wall` to `gcc` or `g++` to get almost all warnings.
- run it with `./helloworld`
- debug it with `gdb ./helloworld`, then

  1. use the `help` command
  2. use the `b main` command to add a breakpoint in `main` and likewise for your `hello` function.
  3. run it under `gdb` using `r`
  4. use `bt` to get a backtrace
  5. use `p` to print some variable
  6. use `c` to continue the execution of the debugged program.
- write a tiny `Makefile` to be able to build your `helloworld` program using `make`
- learn how to call `make` (with `M-x compile`) and `gdb` (with `M-x gdb`) from inside Emacs

Learn more about [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (to detect most memory leaks). Perhaps consider using [Boehm's GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) in some of your applications.

Comment: If he's very new to unix in general, some of the advanced books you mention (although very good) might be a bit much.  Quite a few years ago I spent an hour or two in the bookstore reading _Unix for Dummies_ and I was pleasantly surprised.  It's old (circa 2004) but at its level I doubt too much has changed.

Comment: +1 for the Bash scripting guide recommendation alone. All good recommendations here.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a lot of things to learn.  I won't give you details, but as someone who's done unix and c/c++ development for a couple decades now I'll try to give you some topics to start with.

My main advice is to start experimenting.  Write the most trivial program you can in C or C++ (something that prints "Hello there, world!" is traditional) and figure out how to compile and run it from the command line.  Then, once you've got a compiled version, start it up under the debugger and play around with breakpoints, printing expressions, etc, etc.  Once you've got this simplest program up and running and you sort of understand what the debugger is telling you, add a class, function, struct, or whatever else feels like a good small step and go through the cycle again.  You'll proceed much faster this way than if you start with a very large program.

Still at a very high level, here are a handful of topics you'll need to figure out at least a bit about.  Note that the "learn by starting small" approach works well for any of the topics below.

- Running `g++`: it has pretty good online documentation for the command line syntax, and although you're bound to find it intimidating at first, try to look for the simplest starting point.
- Find a text editor to use.  `Vim` and `emacs` are traditional (and very very powerful) but both have a relatively steep learning curve.  If you have someone around to help you, that's so much the better.  There are other alternatives, but as an `emacs` user myself, I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with them.
- Get familiar with `gdb`.  It's an incredibly powerful tool for understanding your program.  Again, it has extensive online documentation that will repay close reading.
- Some familiarity with standard unix commands will be useful: `ls`, `cd`, and moving basics of the navigating unix directories; `grep` for quickly searching source files.
- You'll have to get used to the *command line* approach versus the *ide approach*.  The former is the traditional unix developer model, where you put together the operations you want from a collection of other tools, rather than having the ide hide most of this knowledge from you.

If your project is multi-file, and especially if it's a full-semester project, you might also consider learning something about the following topics.

- `Make` is a tool for describing how to compile and link a multi-file project so that you don't have to remember how to do it by hand each time.  `Make`, unfortunately, has a well-deserved reputation for being tricky to use, but this is mostly true in very large projects spanning multiple directories, and there are probably good simple examples online.
- I would strongly consider making use of a source code control system such as `git` or `hg`, even for a few relatively small project.  It's so much safer to have an archived version of what you've done so that you can back up quickly.  Both `git` and `hg` are overkill for a small one-shot project, but they are worth learning on their own.  Conventional wisdom as I understand it today is that they're very similar in philosophy and core functionality, but that `hg` is definitely a bit more consistent at the command line level, and therefore easier to start with.

I suspect this is rather intimidating, especially if you've got effectively no exposure to a unix command environment before.  I re-emphasize my first piece of advice above: learn by starting simple and experimenting.  This minimizes the amount of new stuff you're having to wrap your head around at any given point in time.