# How to start off with a embedded linux development environment

Tags: linux, windows, embedded

I come from a windows background and i am proficient with the .net platform. For work, i need to bring up a custom embedded system platform. We have bought the pandaboard ES as the test platform. The application is to stream images over the wifi. If you think about it, we are building something similar to a netgear router - the only difference being when you log into the device it serves images.

Because my background is in windows i am not quite sure how to start off with embedded linux development. in reading through various sites i have come to the conclusion that going to linux as development host is the best option.

Can some one point to me in the right direction regarding the set up. I have a windows machine that will be used for development purposes. I can either do a virtual box or setup a partition for linux. But the finer details are what throwing me off..what i need to know is

1) once i install linux what other software do I need - Code blocks, 
2) what about toolchain
3) How to debug - through serial port ?
4) Is there a way to send the image built directly to the CF card?

Thanks

Comment: Strong, strong suggestion: buy this book: [Embedded Linux Primer, Christpher Hallinan](http://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Linux-Primer-Practical-Real-World/dp/0137017839)

Comment: PS: If I were you, I would seriously consider using Linux as your development workstation.  Or at least set up a Linux VM running on your Windows host.  IMHO...

Comment: Even if the question is interesting and well formulated, I'm not sure you got the right Stack for that. My guess would be: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: This question is too broad, and at least 4 questions as you indicate at the end of this post.  Can you break it down into the parts you feel you would need answered to accomplish your larger goal?

Comment: for 4) - answer yes  - use `dd if=image.img of=/dev/YOURDEVICEWITHCF`

Comment: + why use CF ? cf is expensive big and i suspect energy noneffective, here already many cheap mmc/sd controllers

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to install linux on your desktop or laptop, perhaps
In a virtual machine.

Then, learn to compile on the command line (the order of program arguments to `gcc` is important).

Start an editor like `emacs`. Take half an hour to follow its tutorial.

Edit the helloworld.c file.

Compile it with

```
   gcc -Wall -g helloworld.c -o hello
```

Improve it till no warnings are given.

Use

```
    ./hello
```

To run it.

Learn to use [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) with your own `Makefile`.

Use a version control system like [git](http://scm-git.com/).

Learn to use cross compilation tools.

#### addenda

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13024567/841108) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13227972/841108).

Cross-building is not very different from native Linux building, except for the names of the cross-compilation tools.

But my feeling is that installing Linux and learning to develop Linux applications on Linux will teach you a lot of skills necessary for cross-development targeted for embedded Linux systems. So read material about [Advanved Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [Advanced Unix Programming](http://baseparth.com/aup).

[Remote debugging](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html) thru the serial port should be possible.

Comment: All, thanks a lot for your response. I have ordered the Embedded linux primer book. I hope its going to be of great help.

Comment: @LightStriker thanks for your comment. I shall post in programmers as well.

Comment: Comming from a windows/.net/ms visual background, emacs/vi is not the easiest route. IDEs like code blocks, eclipse, qt creator, kdevelop are going to feel much more familiar.