# Run C++ code with PHP

Tags: php, c++

I have a some C++ code I would like to have run on a server and return the output. I know that

`exec("./myprogram.exe", $out);`

should run the program and `$out` will hold the output. Currently I can't get output from my program... it outputs it using `cout` and I compiled it on Windows, the server I want to run it on is Linux based. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to recompile your C++ code on Linux, using first `g++ -Wall -g`  (order of arguments to `g++` [matters a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13227972/841108)) -then some other compiler arguments-  since `-Wall` asks for all warnings and `-g` for debugging information. Once your code is debugged on Linux you could also pass `-O2` to ask [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to optimize.

Then you need to use the [popen](http://php.net/popen) function of PHP to get the output of your command (thru a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)). As documented, use e.g. [fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read from the pipe handle, and don't forget to [pclose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pclose.php) it. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988397/841108).

Comment: how does argument order matter here?

Comment: I added a link to a previous answer; it is the order of arguments to `g++` that I was talking about.

Comment: It (order of program arguments to `g++`) usually is not irrelevant, especially if your compiled program uses some libraries. The OP did not tell us what is his C++ program and how big is it ...

Comment: in case you have a selective hearing: you ignored the word **here**. "order of -Wall and -g is important" - that's the way I read your sentence.

Comment: It is relevant *here* especially if the C++ program has several source files and use several libraries. You won't link it successfully with `g++ -lgmp foo.cc bar.cc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -o foobar`; and the "order matters" refers to put `-Wall -g` *first* ....

Comment: @Karoly: Please recall that I am not a native English speaker. I'm sure you might have difficulties having all that chat in e.g. French or Russian!

Comment: I have myprogram.out now, how can I read the output from `$handle = popen('./myprogram.out', 'r');`?