# What do terms like static compiler and runtime compilers practically mean?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, static-linking

I'm working to learn C++ more and trying to know basics about different compilers and their technologies. I googled this a lot but every time I stepped through I happened to meet new terms which need more explanation. So, what do these terms such as static compiling, dynamic linking and so on which reside in this topic mean in action?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're asking for, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with [tag:static-analysis].

Comment: I read somewhere about static-analysis, precisely in the about section of a subset tool of LLVM. I mentioned that because I thought It might be related to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some languages like C++ compile all of a program to "native machine code" understood by the CPU before it starts running (i.e. actually being used).  That's "static compilation".

Other languages (e.g. Java) use "Just In Time" compilers to produce CPU-native code from some other "byte-code" representation of the program, but do so only once they start running.  That's "runtime" compilation.

Many other languages (e.g. common python, perl, ruby, Java implementations) use an "interpreter", which means they have native code that keeps consulting some manner of "byte-code" to work out what to do next.  (Some very basic inter-company or specialised interpreters even keep consulting the source code without ever generating a more compact byte-code representation thereof, but no popular language does that - it's awfully slow and clumsy).

A single language may potentially use any combination of these approaches, but in general it's either static compilation, or an interpreter that might add a just-in-time compiler to speed up execution.

Sometimes, a single language has implementations that use different approaches, for example: there are limited C++ interpreters (like http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint, but I've never heard of it being used "in anger"), and systems that compile python to native code.

For "dynamic linking": say you have a function "void f();" that does something wonderful.  If you put that function in a library for use by many applications, you could "statically link" the function into a specific application to take a "snapshot" of `f()`'s functionality at the specific point in time your program's executable is being created.  Then if `f()` changes later you have to re-link and redistribute your application to incorporate the changes to `f()`.  Alternatively, you could put `f()` into a dynamic linked library, which means a separate library file containing `f()` is distributed alongside - or independently from - your program.  Each time your program starts running, if looks to the dynamic library file for the code to use for `f()`.  So, if you distribute an updated dynamic library you can update `f()` without redistributing all the application programs that call `f()`.  Sometimes, that's just a better model for distributing updated software to your users, and avoiding getting each individual application program involved in the distribution of updates to `f()`.  (Occasionally it's a disaster because a dynamic version of `f()` hasn't actually been tested with the application, and does something subtly differently that breaks the application).

Answer (score 4):

About static or dynamic [linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), read also [Levine's *Linker & Loader* book](http://www.iecc.com/linker/).

About shared or static libraries, read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO)

For shared objects (or libraries) on Linux, read [Drupper's *How To Write Shared Libraries* paper](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

You could load plugins with [dlopen(3)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) but then read [C++ dlopen mini-howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/).

[Compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) is usually static, since it is [ahead of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler) (e.g. when compiling with GCC). Sometimes, a [just in time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_In_Time_compilation) is done (e.g. by most [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JVM)s).

If coding in C++ on Linux, you'll want to compile with `g++ -Wall -g` (and later use `-O2` to ask GCC to optimize when your program is debugged). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13024567/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108) hints.

Also, learn [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) and use the latest [GCC 4.8.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) compiler (GCC 4.9 might be released in a few weeks, e.g. in march or april 2014).